# How to upgrade blueimp jquery file upload to use jquery-widget 1.13

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, blueimp

We are aiming to upgrade our jQuery UI to version 13.1 due to security concerns arising from known vulnerabilities in the previous version. However, we've encountered an obstacle: even with the latest version of blueimp-file-upload (10.32.0), it bundles an older version (1.12) of jQuery Widget. Consequently, this forces our package manager to install an outdated version of jQuery UI. Upon inspecting the source code for blueimp-file-upload, we've found that it's no longer supported. Has anyone encountered and resolved this issue, the functionality is used in several places and quite integrated so not easy to switch to another package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.